# Filefield in django Model, hide the link to file and clear box in template

Tags: django

I have a model Test with a filefield:

```
class Test(models.Model):
  file = models.FileField(upload_to='file', blank=True, null=True)
```

In the template i render it via the form:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Test
    fields = '__All__'
```

In the template i do:

```
 <td  class="tg-0lax">{{ test.file }}</td>
```

In the template its working fine, i gat the file upload possibility
But this also shows the clickable link to the file in the template. I dont want that. So i want to render it buy without the link to the file (only the upload possibility)
Is this possible

Comment: Are you talking about that checkbox which allows you to clear the file? If you remove that how would you clear the file (Or keep the old one without clearing) without that?

Comment: Yes, the file is saved via django fille system, so not served via /Media folder. But then the file link is not correct! So i want the file link removed.